# Bitcoin Wallet for Android/Windows with Full Control of BTC (keys)

Tags: wallet, multibit, android

I used to manage my bitcoin by using MultiBit for Windows. I had full control of them, without any involvement from a 3rd party.

But as a person i know wanted to get bitcoin and a Android wallet, i started to see if there was a MultiBit version for Android, just to realize MultiBit for Windows is discontinued.

I stumbled into [Web Wallet difference](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58872/web-wallet-difference) but it's not exactly the question i am asking.

On Google Play the results aren't familiar at all and the Blockchain app asks for e-mail/etc and the BTC will be stored by them, and i want an app that give me full control of the btc/private keys.

So what apps can be used for Android/Windows that meet the criteria i am asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of wallets for Android & Windows in which you are on control your private keys. [Here](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) you can find a list recommended by Bitcoin Core.

Personally, I recommend Mycelium because is very complete.

Comment: Yes. i recommended Mycelium and also installed myself, liking it very much-